# How does VirtualBox handle thread priority in the guest?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, priority

Assume a scenario in which a VirtualBox VM is running a multi-threaded app which is maxing out all available CPU cores. However, the threads run at low priority, thus if anything else were to run on the VM, it would do so at no noticeable performance penalty (assuming at least normal priority for the other task).

Let us furthermore assume that VirtualBox has been assigned as many virtual CPUs as available on the host system, thus the VM could max out every single core on the host.

How would this affect the performance of a thread running on the host system (assuming normal priority)? Is the guest system inside a VirtualBox subject to scheduling by the host OS kernel at all, or do virtualization extensions bypass that? How is CPU time divided between the host and VMs, and how does thread priority inside the VM affect this?